# Async sockets - identifying unique connections

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asyncsocket

I have a server that accepts async socket connections from multiple clients.  Right now I am assigning them a server-side unique ID dependent on their incoming IP address & port.  My concern is - what if 2 clients connect from the same IP & behind an NAT.  Is there a better way to determine this?

```
 private static int DetermineSocketToConnectionID(Socket handler)
        {
            int connectionIDForHandler = 0;

            string uniqueIPString = handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

            if (Client1Buffers.UserIPAddress == uniqueIPString)
            {
                connectionIDForHandler = 1;
            }
            if (Client2Buffers.UserIPAddress == uniqueIPString)
            {
                connectionIDForHandler = 2;
            }

            return connectionIDForHandler;
        }
```

Comment: Two clients behind NAT will have the same IP address but different ports.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off having those clients authenticate themselves with the server on their first connection and pass you something you can use to identify them other than trusting network information. This is exactly why sessions and cookies were created for logging in clients to web servers. You can do something similar by handshaking with the client and passing them back a uid, which they would then need to pass back to the server on each subsequent connect.